# Currency Formatting for euro in word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I did currency formatting for Dollar. It works fine. Same currency formatting I want to do for other currencies also like Euro, Pound. 
Below is the code that I tried. Pls help.

Code:

```
Sub CurrencyFormat_UK()
'
' Currency formating
'

Dim oCl As Word.Cell
Dim oRng As Range
'
' Condition to check the selected data
'
  If Selection.Type = wdSelectionIP Or _
      Not Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
    MsgBox "Select a cell or range of cells before running" _
      & " this macro.", , "Nothing Selected"
    Exit Sub
  End If
  For Each oCl In Selection.Cells
    Set oRng = oCl.Range
    '
    'Drop of the end of cell mark
    '
    oRng.End = oRng.End - 1
    With oRng
      If IsNumeric(oRng) Then
        .Text = FormatCurrency(Expression:=.Text, NumDigitsAfterDecimal:=2, _
                IncludeLeadingDigit:=vbTrue, UseParensForNegativeNumbers:=vbTrue)
      End If
      If oRng.Characters.count = 1 Then GoTo Skip
      On Error GoTo Skip
      'Catch errors here
      If InStr(oRng.Text, "€") = False Then
        oRng.Font.Color = wdColorRed
        oRng.Select
        MsgBox "Cell content is not numerical.", , "Error"
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
      End If
Skip:
    End With
  Next oCl
lbl_Exit:
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: What error does it give? I mean how can we help if you don't say what's not working??

Comment: Actually "FormatCurrency" function which is used in code formats in Dollar automatically. Is there any other way that can format in other currencies also?

Comment: If you want someone to do the work for you, you'll have to pay a programmer. This website is for programmers asking help with some doubt or error you might have, not a "please do everything for me, ktkxbai!"

Comment: Come On!!!When I said "Please do everything for me". I just asked pls tell me if any other function is there instead of "FormatCurrency" that can be used for other currencies. If you are not ready to help, avoid comment.

Comment: Aaaah, got it. You want to format a number into the non-system currency? Don't use FormatCurrency, use NumberFormat instead. I'll write a better example bellow if you wait 2 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

Just use NumberFormat instead.

Let's say I want to format the whole B column to GBP ( £ ) from the SheetCur sheet. The code would be:

```
Worksheets("SheetCur").Columns("A").NumberFormat = "£#,##0.00_)"
```

This would create stuff looking like £555,00. If you want to leave a space between the currency and the number just leave a space in the string as well:

```
.NumberFormat = "£ #,##0.00_)"
```

Likewise if you want the currency after the number, you could use:

```
.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00 £_)"
```

Comment: What's the _ after 0.00 for?

Comment: I believe it's a space. I'm also seeing that ) that I don't think should be there